# Can't get the data from an elastic index

Tags: kibana, vega

with your help, i managed to create a dynamic textbox whose data is contained directly in the vega code. However, the goal is to display this textbox in a kibana dashboard. The textbox should get the data from an elastic index. I want the 'questionText'-column of the index to be the source of my textbox. So I tried

```
"text": {"signal": "data('_source')[0]['questionText']"}
```

But that doesn't work. This is the code of my attempt:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "url": {
      "index": "questions",
    }
    "format": {"property": "hits.hits"}
  },

  "marks":[  
    {"type": "text",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "fill": {"value": "#000"},
          "text": {"value": "TextZeile01"},
          //"text": {"signal": "data('_source')[0]['questionText']"}
          //"text": {"signal": "_source[0]['questionText']"},
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

index 'questions' is simply this:

[image]

Anyone know how to do it?